# Python 3.6 & MySQL 8.0.21 on MacOS: How to give table camelCase column names?

Tags: mysql, case-sensitive, camelcasing

I have an API response that I would like to store in a MySQL table with column names that are identical to the names used in the response. In this case some of them are case sensitive, in particular camelCase. It seems MySQL is not accepting this. What can I do to change this?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You cant store a camelCase string in MySQL?

Comment: I am only talking about the column names, not the values.

Comment: I already read that before. To some degree yes

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, column names are not case sensitive. As a demonstration:

```
SELECT Db, db, dB, DB FROM mysql.db
```

In MySQL, table names can be case sensitive, dependent on the operating system/file system, and settings of some MySQL system variables.

---

Saying "seems MySQL is not accepting this" is an imprecise description of the observed behavior. It's not possible to provide any additional help, without the question being revised to be a little more specific in regards to more accurately and precisely describing the actual observed behavior.

If you have a test case that demonstrates case sensitivity of column names in MySQL, we'd definitely want to see it.